# How to setup Stealth Forwarders and URL Redirects in Google Cloud?

Tags: domain-name-system, google-cloud-platform

I'm having a few points of confusion around Google Cloud DNS. Currently I have a DNS/Name Server Provider (easydns) that has my domain setup with the following record entries.

host => @
type => Stealth Forwarder
points at => someplace.com

host => www
type => URL Redirect
points at => http://someplace.com

host => www.another
type => URL Redirect
points at => http://another.someplace.com

These entries seem pretty common but I've no idea how to add URL Redirects or Stealth Forwarders to Google Cloud. I've been looking through the docs but am still a bit confused where these elements go. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EEAA is correct: for HTTP, if you want to redirect, you'll have to use the platform to handle the redirect, otherwise you use something like:

`nickname.server.com    CNAME    icantrememberthisextremelylongnameyousillyperson.server.com`

...in your DNS records (your DNS service will have a bind.conf or similar). [Google's documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference-uris) explains this very thing.

Answer (score 1):

Redirects are a function of HTTP, not DNS.

If you need to perform HTTP redirects, you'll need to stand up your own HTTP service.